# WebViewWidget iframe Appears Inset on Pixel 6a

Tags: flutter, iframe

Have some Flutter code with a `WebViewWidget` that loads a youtube embed video in an `iframe` element where on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 tablet the youtube video in the `iframe` fills the `WebViewWidget` accordingly but, when testing the same code on a Pixel 6a mobile, the youtube embed video in the `iframe` appears inset on the top-left corner of the `WebViewWidget` at less than half the size and I am not sure why?

Only obvious differences I can think of between Galaxy Tab S4 and Pixel 6a are Android versions (Tab S4: Android 10, Pixel 6a: Android 14) and dpi (Tab S4: ~287 ppi density, Pixel 6a: ~429 ppi density).

[image]

Code:

```
var html = '<iframe width="$width" height="$height" allowtransparency="true" style="border: 10px; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; background: #FFFFFF;" src="$ytLink" ></iframe>';

_controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..loadHtmlString(html);
  
return Container(
  width: width,
  height: height,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: margin, right: margin, top: edge, bottom : edge),
  child: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller));
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by changing `iframe`'s width and height to be 100% instead of specific values in pixels:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" style="border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #FFFFFF;" src="$ytLink" ></iframe>
```

For some reason using specific width and height values for the `iframe` on Pixel 6a does not match the `WebViewWidget`'s parent `Container` width and height (which is also supposed to be the same width and height).